# Cannot create hybrid mobile project in JBoss developer studio

Tags: cordova, jboss, hybrid-mobile-app

I m learning hybrid mobile project in Red Hat JBoss developer studio. I have already gone through some sites learn this. But i m stuck in the first stage. I m unable to create the project. I select new project -> hybrid mobile (cordova) application project. After that i gave my project name , id and after clicking next it ask to select hybrid mobile engine in which there is Android and Windows phone8 option.I cant click any of those options.There is download and search button but i dont know what it does.And the Next of Finish button is disable.so i cant go further and thus cant create the project. I have added the picture.

Please advise me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a Red Hat Mobile Application Platform [1] integration, it won't work with just the JBDS installed.  So you need to have the product installed (currently not fully open sourced).
[1] https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/mobile